# Constraint element to the TextInputLayout text (inside the TextInputLayout)

Tags: android, xml

I have a TextInputLayout with only an EditText inside it.
I'm interested in adding a TextView of my own to it, as a potential error text (e.g. "invalid email") and have the following constraints:
1. end of my TextView to end of the TextInputLayout
2. top of my TextView to top of already existing hint, when the latter is on *top* (preferably with the same text size, but I'm assuming I can achieve that by playing with the sizes a little bit), meaning some text has already been inserted.

Is there any way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditText has a facility of setError(). You need to put some conditions where to set error and where to clear.
No need of extra textview for error message.

Comment: I see, I'm trying it now and this looks good.
Is there, however, a method to do what I described anyway?

Comment: You should not mess with predefined VIEWS or UI and its properties with your custom views and its adjustment.